# Search not returning any results for custom profile property

Tags: 2007, search, user-profile

I've added a new property (lets call it CarReg) to our users profile. It's set as a 15 character string with multiple values allowed.

When you see the property in a profile it's a clickable link that searches for CarReg:"XXXXXXX" and this returns no results. Searching without the CarReg: prefix returns results as expected.

Does anyone know how to get this working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your new property as a managed property at metadata properties under search administration on you SSP?  If it's listed there, have you done a full index since adding the property?

Answer (score 1):

First crawl your content so you have a list of all properties. Then promote the property to a Managed Property in the search admin. Now you can filter on that specific field.